# Does ‘one’ mean ‘one team’ or ‘one family’ in ‘we are the one’?

Tags: grammatical-number

Does ‘one’ mean ‘one team’ or ‘one family’ in ‘we are the one’, not ‘one thing/person’? The dictionary doesn’t say ‘one’ means ‘one group’ though.

https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/pitbull/weareoneoleola.html

Comment: It could mean anything. What's the context?

Comment: @gotube It’s a song name.

Comment: When asking questions here, it's best to give as much context and do as much work as you can for the people answering the questions. Please edit the question to say that it's a song title, and include a link to the lyrics. The phrase "we are the one" by itself isn't meaningful

Comment: Wow. You and the rest of the ELL crew really need to find better music to listen to. Reading those vague and vapid lyrics is time I'll never get back. Ugh. What does "we are one" mean here? My best guess (because JLo and Pitbull are terrible songwriters) is that we are one human family.

Comment: @FeliniusRex You mean they created word ‘one’ meaning one human family even though that’s wrong according to dictionaries?

Comment: Nowhere in that song is the phrase "we are *the* one." "We are one," sans "the," clearly refers to "one people" as it is couched in the context of raising flags in the air, waving them, and showing the world where you're from.

Comment: What do you mean, 'wrong according to dictionaries'? 'We are all one' and similar phrases are a common way of expressing the idea that people are united in a common belief or relationship.

Comment: First, it's not wrong according to the dictionary. What's wrong is your understanding. Second, I get why you're confused, because raising flags doesn't unify people, but celebrates their differences. Nevertheless, unity is what the crappy songwriters were trying to say -- unity in being human, unity in the fact that we all love and live (I guess?).